# separating arquillian deployment from running test cases

Tags: jboss-arquillian

I have many test cases running in arquillian managed jboss container. The deployment is big and takes time. The problem is that for maintaining a test case I have to re-run it numerous times, which also deploys the application with each run and wastes a lot of time.

Is it possible to separate the deployment from test cases

Answer (score 0):

The core module itself does not support it out of the box. You can however use an extension which provides that capability - suite wide deployments. Have a look here https://github.com/ingwarsw/arquillian-suite-extension